# Low grahic mode 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have been trying to get Ubuntu 12.04 to launch on my Emachine 2828. I was able to load it and use the dual setup with windows xp. I am able to run windows, but I have not been able to run ubuntu. I get the low graphic mode message.. My processor is amd sempron 2800+, and video is via/s3g unichrome igp. I have tried most of the tips posted for low graphics...any help appreciated

Comment: Actually what graphic card do you have? Can you post the output of lspci | grep VGA in your question's description?(Remember that when you get the low graphic message, just press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to drop into a tty session. There you need to give your user name and password and then you have to try the above command I have mentioned)

Comment: VIA/S3G UNICHROME IGP

Answer (score 0):

Maybe driver for your GPU is missing. Do you know what package in it is? If yes, use the Ctrl+Alt+F1 combination to switch to a TTY. Log in (if you've installed Ubuntu), and type:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get -y install NAME_OF_THE_PACKAGE
```

After the successful installion, type:

```
sudo reboot
```

Check the result.

If you don't know the package's name, please look at this [question&answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error). If you need any further help, please write a comment!

Comment: I downloaded the package with windows, not sure how to get it to ubuntu tty to load

Comment: The quickest way is to place that driver to a pendrive. If you connect it, it will mount somewhere to /media. Install 'mc' program(`sudo apt-get -y install mc`), and run it: `sudo mc /media` - it is very similar to Total Commander. Install that driver. I hope that's a .deb, than you can just run a command: `sudo dpkg -i NAME.deb; sudo apt-get install -f`